# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'fss:oauth'

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to build a Java application that accesses data stored in Database.com using the Database.com Java SDK. I have followed the steps given at qucik start guide @ http://forcedotcom.github.com/java-sdk/quick-start. When the application is deployed on tomcat server, i was getting the following exception

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:    Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [security-    config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml];   nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:   Line 15 in XML   document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml] is invalid;   nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching   wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'fss:oauth'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at
```

Here is the **security-config.xml** code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:fss="http://www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity
        http://media.developerforce.com/schema/force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd">

<!-- SFDC OAuth security config -->
<fss:oauth logout-from-force-dot-com="true">
    <fss:connectionName name="forceDatabase"/>
</fss:oauth>


<!-- Configure Spring Security -->
<!-- use-expressions and hasRole only needed if jsp tags are used. 
    If not using jsp tags you can omit the use-expressions property and set access="ROLE_USER" on the intercept-url tags -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">

    <security:anonymous />

    <!--  Uncomment this section to enable security -->

    <!-- 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
     -->

    <!-- sets this as the authentication filter over the default -->
    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter"/>
</security:http>
```

I can see that the element oauth is available at the xsd http://media.developerforce.com/schema/force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd. I have tried changing it to different verisons of xsd. But I was not successful.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think the issue is because it is not able to fins the XSD . Try opening up the jars and see if you can trace the XSD .

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this will help, but I was experiencing some similar issue with the tag: .

This was my XML:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<jaxws:endpoint id="HelloWorldService" implementor="com.client.webservices.ratecard.StandardHelloWorldService" address="/HelloWorldService" />
```

I tried everything without avail, until I discovered that somehow Eclipse proxy was set to direct and I was behind a proxy. Still I was able to get the first set of XSD definitions from the Apache site (http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws) nevertheless within it you can see they are importing a couple more XSD and at this point the redirection was failing and thus I was getting extremely strange errors like this.

Then I set the Eclipse proxy as Native in the preferences and the error magically disappeared.

I hope this will also work in your case.

Comment: Getting out from behind the proxy also solved my issue. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This typically means your classpath is not setup correctly, it is not an xsd issue.  To verify (if you are using Eclipse) you can right click the document and click "validate".  If the xsd validates with Eclipse then you don't have to worry about that part.

What I believe happens is that Spring finds the XSD and validates but then when it encounters the fss:oauth tag it tries to find a Java class that is registered to implement the behavior for that tag and fails.  Are you certain you have the Salesforce jars on your classpath?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried validating the force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd. It was showing the compilation error "Cannot resolve the name 'beans:identifiedType' to a(n) 'type definition'". Not sure how to resolve this issue. are there any jars missing?. Here is the classpath I have used.

Comment: aopalliance-1.0.jar,asm-3.1.jar,aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar,aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar,cglib-2.2.jar,commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,datanucleus-core-2.2.3.jar,datanucleus-enhancer-2.1.0-release.jar,datanucleus-jpa-2.1.7.jar,force-connector-22.0.7-BETA.jar,force-jpa-22.0.7-BETA.jar,force-metadata-api-22.0.0.jar,force-oauth-22.0.7-BETA.jar,force-partner-api-22.0.0.jar, force-springsecurity-22.0.7-BETA.jar, force-wsc-22.0.0.jar,geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar,gson-1.7.1.jar,javax.inject-1.jar,jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar,jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar,js-1.7R2.jar,json-simple-1.1.jar,jstl-1.2.jar,log4j-1.2.15.jar,

Comment: slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar,spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,transaction-api-1.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

I notice in the included schema `force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd`, the prefix `beans` is undefined. What if you modify

`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`

to

`<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`

(and the last line too)?

Answer (score 0):

Following Aravind A advice I simply had this dependency to my POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kubek2k</groupId>
    <artifactId>springockito</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

In fact you just need to put mockito.xsd in your path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the element `fss:oauth` should be defined in a schema (xsd file) listed at [www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity](http://www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity), as defined in the declaration `xmlns:fss="http://www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity"` at the top of the page.

However the **xsd** file that should be in that URL it just isn't there. I guess Salesforce moved it. If you go to [www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity](http://www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity) you see that you get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I observed that the application tried to get the xsd file from the internet instead of using the jar file one. The problem was caused because a mismatch in the xsd location definition between the spring.schemas file and the location specified in the applicationContext.xml file. Changing the url from http://media.developerforce.com/schema/force-springsecurity-1.3.xsd to http://www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity/force-springsecurity-1.3.xsd in the applicationContext.xml file solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this going through an integration tutorial for SFDC.  In my search to resolve the issue I found this [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/java-sdk/issues/31) on the force.com github repo.

According to Github user todc

> The issue, I believe, is with the media.developerforce.com URL, not the salesforce.com URL. Given the age of the repo and the lack of recent activity, I'm guessing the XSD files won't be made available again.
>
> I was able to find archived versions of the XSD file at:
>
> http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.force.sdk/force-springsecurity/22.0.8-BETA/com/force/sdk/springsecurity/config/force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd?av=f
>
> You can package that file into your app and refer to the local copy instead, e.g.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.salesforce.com/schema/springsecurity
                       classpath:force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd">
</beans>
```

> There's probably a better way, but that's what I was able to get working. Good luck!

Github user iandrosov stated

> I now host this "deprecated" fiorsce-springsecurity-1.2.xsd on Heroku to give access to may apps. Sharing my public URL here so it may help others. http://force-spring.herokuapp.com/force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd

I solved this issue by using iandrosov's hosted xsd file, replacing the original

```
http://media.developerforce.com/schema/force-springsecurity-1.3.xsd
```

with his hosted xsd

```
http://force-spring.herokuapp.com/force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd
```

I've done this simply becaus I am doing a tutorial.  For anybody else running into this issue it's probably better to do as Github user todc suggests and

> package the file into your app and refer to the local copy instead.