# cxf web service and spring

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, cxf

I configured a web service Integrated with Spring:

**web.xml**

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Baharan-Framework</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-cxf.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-cxf-xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd  
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <jaxws:endpoint id="userService"
        implementor="org.baharan.ws.userService.AmadUserService" address="/userService" />
</beans>
```

**java file**

```
package org.baharan.ws.userService;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class AmadUserService {

    @WebMethod
    public String test() {
        return "In the name of god...";
    }

}
```

This error occurs when it be deployed in weblogic 12.1.3:

> Caused By: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 85; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxws:endpoint'.

Please help me.

Comment: Sounds like a classpath issue. Is this different than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299754/parser-error-cxf-beans-xml-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-jaxwsendpoi or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711186/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-fs

Comment: What is the version of CXF being used